# Saving ord(characters) from different lines(one string) in different lists

Tags: python-3.x, bioinformatics

i just can't figure it out.
I got a string with some lines.

```
qual=[abcdefg\nabcedfg\nabcdefg]
```

I want to convert my characters to the ascii value and saves those values in an other list for each line.

```
value=[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

But my codes saves them all in one list.

```
values=[1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

First of all my code:

```
for element in qual:
   qs = ord(element)  
   quality_code.append(qs)
```

I also tried to split() the string but the result is still the same

```
qual=line#[:-100]
qually=qual.split()
  for list in qually:
    for element in list:
      qs = ord(element)
      quality.append(qs)
```

My next attempt was:

```
for element in qual:
  qs = ord(element)  
  quality_code.append(qs)
  for position in range(0, len(quality_code)):
    qual_liste[position].append(quality_code[position])
```

With this code an IndexError(list index out of range) occurs.
There is probably a way with try and except but i dont get it.

```
for element in qual:
  qs = ord(element)  
  quality_code.append(qs)
  for position in range(0, len(quality_code)):
    try:
      qual_liste[position].append(quality_code[position])
    except IndexError:
      pass
```

With this code the qual_lists stays empty, probably because of the pass
but i dont know what to insert instead of pass.

Thanks a lot for help. I hope my bad english is excusable .D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, this should do the trick:

```
qual="abcdefg\nabcedfg\nabcdefg"
print([[ord(ii) for ii in i] for i in qual.split('\n')])
```

List comprehension is always the answer.

Comment: @Julian no problem